# Wouldn't placing an inductor instead of a capacitor have the same effect in fans?

Tags: motors

A capacitor is kept in the circuit of a fan to overcome the trouble of having torques in both directions. I would like to know if the capacitor could be replaced with an inductor without resulting in any change in operation of the fan ?

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you a quicky answer until an EE shows up.

No, that won't work. The motor itself is mostly an inductor. To get a phase change you need the capacitor. At least it will be much more effective, smaller and cheaper.

Comment: I think Phil has it pretty well covered.
@Zam; As obviously you have had a large dose of theory for breakfast and the last time I had a bite of that cereal was 40 years ago. Anyway maybe this will help you to understand a little more.How do you connect an inductor in a circuit. How do you charge an inductor? What happens when you add two inductance's? When you have worked those 3 questions out apply the same to capacitors.

Comment: Sorry for necrobumping, I tried it myself, and the fan rotates in the opposite direction due to having opposite phase angle. I calculated that I needed 4.05mH inductor for replacing a 2.5uF capacitor. The torque is lesser than the capacitor though. Also the inductor doesn't fail like a capacitor, and my inductor costed about 1.5x the capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:  The capacitor is used **with** an inductor to create a rotating magnetic field.  There are **two** coils (inductors) in a single-phase motor.

If you apply single-phase ac to a coil, you get a magnetic field which is proportional to the current.  You apply a sine wave current and you get a sine wave magnetic field.  Starts at 0, goes to a maximum NS, back to 0, to a maximum SN, back to 0, repeat.  This will not create rotation.  If you apply that to a motor with a magnetized rotor, the rotor vibrates but does not rotate.

On a three-phase motor, the application of three-phase power creates a 360° revolving magnetic field because the three coils (A, B & C) experience different phases of current.  As shown by linked image.

From [AC Motor Theory](http://www.tpub.com/doeelecscience/electricalscience2143.htm)

[image: Magnetic Field created by three phase current]

But single-phase current does not create a revolving magnetic field, so we have to cheat.  We apply the single-phase current to a winding **AND** use a capacitor to phase shift the applied voltage to another angle and apply that to a second winding.

This second winding reaches it's peak magnetic field not at the same time, so it creates a torque in one direction to cause rotation.

From [Electrical Training](http://electriciantraining.tpub.com/14177/css/Figure-4-3-Two-Phase-Rotating-Field-89.htm)

[image: Single-Phase Magnetic Rotation]

There are different types which use capacitors to create a phase shift.

- Capacitor Start, which has a capacitor and coil for starting. Centripetal switch disconnects coil as it gets up to full speed.
- Capacitor Run has a capacitor and coil in the circuit at all times.  Better torque.

But some designs, Shaded Pole use just inductors with different sized wires to create torque, but torque is significantly lower so it is only useful for light loads.

Either way, two coils must be used to create rotation in a single-phase motor.